# Given right-angle triangle $\triangle ABC$ $(\angle A=90^o)$, with $BC=10$ and $AC=6$. Find the length of $DE$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Given right-angle triangle $\triangle ABC$$(\angle A=90^o)$, with $BC=10$ and $AC=6$. Circle is tangent to $BC$, goes through $A$ and intersects with $AB$ and $AC$ at the points $E$ and $D$ respectively. Find the length of $DE$.

[image]

I tried to solve this question as follows:

$AB=8$ from Pythagoras.

Since $DA\perp AE$ then $DE$ is diameter of the circle.

After drawing it out accurately, I see that $DE=4.8$, but I don't know how to work this out mathematically. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: Are Trignometric functions allowed ?

Comment: @AnasKhaled yes, but please don't do something that uses a calculator, as I'm trying to understand how to solve this question, without the use of a calculator

Comment: There is insufficient information to determine the length of $DE$.

Comment: Sorry, never mind, trig functions weren't necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagrams below shows that there is simply insufficient information to determine the length of $DE$.

[image]

[image]

[image]